# moving with google street view api

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My question is, is there any way to have a animated street view with automatic moving forward with it's web street view API?

I have a polyline of places that I have been and I want to have a animated street view.

Comment: Did this ever end up working in any robust way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. If you have the polyline you have its coordinates. So what you would have to do is getting the coordinates of the path (just the vertices or as many steps as you want between the vertices) and set those coordinates as StreetView position via `setPosition` with a certain delay one after the other. To get the coordinates you can use `polyline.getPath()`, which will return an array.

With `heading` (and `pitch`) of the `StreetViewPov` object you can change the view direction of the StreetView panorama along the route (if you want to).

Comment: how can i make a function to set the position with delay and change it?

Comment: You could write a function `setPositionWithDelay(position)` in wich you use the `setTimeout`-method like `setTimeout(function (){ /*Set the position*/ }, 1000);` to execute `setPosition` function with the given delay. You could also add the delay as argument to this function to use different delays for different positions.